# Getting corresponding text value along with input text

Tags: php, html, input

I have a form in which I have many fields. I want to know how to get value of the corresponding label of the input text. For example:

```
<p><input type="text" name="complaints[]"/> Jaw pain</p>
<p><input type="text" name="complaints[]"/> Jaw clicking</p>
<p><input type="text" name="complaints[]"/> Jaw locking</p>
<p><input type="text" name="complaints[]"/> Limited mouth opening</p>
<p><input type="text" name="complaints[]"/> Facial pain</p>
```

I can get the values of `input type=text` which I'm processing in PHP by using `$_POST[complaints]`. I want to get the value of the corresponding text as well i.e Jaw pain, Jaw clicking etc..

I have more than 30 fields each with different text value. How do I get this text too?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `<input type="text" name="complaints[Jaw pain]"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign names to your input inside the [].

Example:

```
<p><input type="text" name="complaints[jaw-pain]"/> Jaw pain</p>
<p><input type="text" name="complaints[jaw-clicking]"/> Jaw clicking</p>
<p><input type="text" name="complaints[jaw-locking]"/> Jaw locking</p>
<p><input type="text" name="complaints[limited-mouth]"/> Limited mouth opening</p>
<p><input type="text" name="complaints[facial-pain]"/> Facial pain</p>
```

This will result in array values in $_POST accessible like:

```
$_POST["complaints"]["jaw-pain"]
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: thank you for your reply. How would I access $_POST["complaints"]["jaw-pain"]. Since I have many fields, can I loop it?

Comment: Of course you can, `$_POST['complaints']` is an array and you have defined all keys. Use something like foreach : `foreach( $_POST['complaints'] as $name => $value ) {}`. With this, `$name` is the field name and `$value` the user entered value.

Answer (score -2):

This will work with your code :

```
$_POST["complaints"][0];
$_POST["complaints"][1];
$_POST["complaints"][2];
$_POST["complaints"][3];
```

Etc..